# tkinter multilistbox lists are independent of each other

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0NwQ.png)I want to create multiple lists with this code and let the lists I create work with each other. When I make mlb.get (ACTIVE), the value in the list is clicked. The get command is not synchronized with other lists.
The info function creates a section on the side and lists the information on the clicked line.
The MULTILISTBOX class needs to make lists and work together.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import apply as apply

class MultiListbox(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, lists):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.lists = []
        for l, w in lists:
            frame = Frame(self);
            frame.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
            Label(frame, text=l, borderwidth=1, relief=RAISED).pack(fill=X)
            lb = Listbox(frame, width=w, borderwidth=0, selectborderwidth=0,
                         relief=FLAT, exportselection=FALSE)
            lb.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
            self.lists.append(lb)
            lb.bind('<B1-Motion>', lambda e, s=self: s._select(e.y))
            lb.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e, s=self: s._select(e.y))
            lb.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: 'break')
            lb.bind('<B2-Motion>', lambda e, s=self: s._b2motion(e.x, e.y))
            lb.bind('<Button-2>', lambda e, s=self: s._button2(e.x, e.y))
        frame = Frame(self);
        frame.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
        Label(frame, borderwidth=1, relief=RAISED).pack(fill=X)
        #sb = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=self._scroll)
        #sb.pack(expand=YES, fill=Y)
        #self.lists[0]['yscrollcommand'] = sb.set

    def _select(self, y):
        row = self.lists[0].nearest(y)
        self.selection_clear(0, END)
        self.selection_set(row)
        return 'break'

    def _button2(self, x, y):
        for l in self.lists: l.scan_mark(x, y)
        return 'break'

    def _b2motion(self, x, y):
        for l in self.lists: l.scan_dragto(x, y)
        return 'break'

    def _scroll(self, *args):
        for l in self.lists:
            apply(l.yview, args)

    def curselection(self):
        return self.lists[0].curselection()

    def delete(self, first, last=None):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.delete(first, last)

    def get(self, first, last=None):
        result = []
        for l in self.lists:
            result.append(l.get(first, last))
        if last: return apply(map, [None] + result)
        return result

    def index(self, index):
        self.lists[0].index(index)

    def insert(self, index, *elements):
        for e in elements:
            i = 0
            for l in self.lists:
                l.insert(index, e[i])
                i = i + 1

    def size(self):
        return self.lists[0].size()

    def see(self, index):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.see(index)

    def selection_anchor(self, index):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.selection_anchor(index)

    def selection_clear(self, first, last=None):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.selection_clear(first, last)

    def selection_includes(self, index):
        return self.lists[0].selection_includes(index)

    def selection_set(self, first, last=None):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.selection_set(first, last)

def info():
    yazi.after(2000,info)
    if mlb.curselection():
        yazi.config(text=mlb.get(ACTIVE))
        print(mlb.get(ACTIVE))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    tk = Tk()
    frame=Frame(tk)
    frame2=Frame(tk)
    screen_width = tk.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = tk.winfo_screenheight()
    sol=int(screen_width*60/100)
    frame.config(width=sol)
    frame2.config(width=screen_width-sol)

    Label(tk, text='MultiListbox').pack()
    mlb = MultiListbox(frame, (('Bağlantı Noktası', 15), ('Cihaz Adı', 50), ('Seri Numarası', 20), ('Boyut', 10), ('İlerleme', 25), ('Durum', 20)))
    for i in range(20):
        mlb.insert(END, ('sda%d' % i, 'Sandisk bla bla bla %d' % i, '85545696324 54112','1000GB','//////////////%d'% i , 'Hazırmıyızzzz %d' % i))
    mlb.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    yazi=Label(frame2)
    yazi.pack()
    info()
    frame.pack(side=LEFT)
    frame2.pack(side=RIGHT)
    tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: use `lb.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", function)` to run function when you select element in `ListBox` and then you can change content in other `Listbox`

Comment: maybe you should send `lb` to binded functions so they would work with different lists.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Multiple `Listbox` in class `MultiListbox` should behave in sync by clicked in one `Listbox`.

Change/add the following:

1. Bind to event `'<<ListboxSelect>>'`

   ```
   class MultiListbox(Frame):
       def __init__(self, master, lists):
           ...
           for l, w in lists:
               ...
               lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.on_select)
   ```
2. Change your global `def info():` to a class method `def on_select(...`

   ```
   def on_select(self, event):
       w = event.widget
       curselection = w.curselection()

       if curselection:
           self.selection_clear(0, self.size())
           self.selection_set(curselection)

           mlb_get = mlb.get(curselection)
           yazi.config(text=mlb_get)
           print(mlb_get)
   ```
3. In `__main__` remove the statement: `info()`

   ```
   # info()
   ```

Comment: I did what you wrote. The program did not output anything I changed but did not get results.

Comment: @MuhammetOnurAslan: **Edit** your questions code to show your attempt.